# sscanf equivalent in linux bash

Tags: bash, scanf

I want to extract a number that appears in the middle of a script in linux bash:

```
APPLES_STR="We have 123 apples."
NUM=?????
```

In C I'd do something like:

```
int num;
const char *str = "We have 123 apples."
sscanf(str, "We have %d apples.", &num);
```

How do I do that in linux bash?

Comment: I would use `awk`.
PoC:`echo "We have 123 apples." | awk '{print $3}'`

Comment: Alternative that doesn't assume the location of the number: `echo "We have 123 apples." | egrep -o '[0-9]+'`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `bash` and a regex:

```
sscanf() {
  local str="$1"
  local format="$2"
  [[ "$str" =~ $format ]]
}

sscanf "We have 123 apples and 42 peaches." "We have (.*) apples and (.*) peaches."
```

You will find the matches in array BASH_REMATCH from field 1.

```
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
echo "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
```

Output:

```
123
42
```

Comment: This is better than `expr match` which I had been using. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

Another way to approach the `sscanf()` look alike would be to pass in a regex type pattern to match and then use the `+(...)` extglob pattern to replace all occurrences in the input string with `"(.*)"` to then let `[[ .. =~ .. ]]` populate the `BASH_REMATCH` without having to pass a duplicate of the string with the `"(.*)"` inserted manually. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

shopt -s extglob

sscanf () {
    local regex="$2"
    local str="${1//+(${regex})/(.*)}"
    [[ $1 =~ $str ]]
}

sscanf "We have 123 apples and 42 peaches." "[[:digit:]]"

declare -p BASH_REMATCH
```

This is essentially what the great answer by @Cyrus shows, it's just another approach to building the search string.

**Example Output**

```
$ bash sscanf.sh
declare -ar BASH_REMATCH=([0]="We have 123 apples and 42 peaches." [1]="123" [2]="42")
```

(**note:** shamelessly borrowing example text from @Cyrus)